# Experimental calculation and $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, quantum-mechanics

I have been reading [this article](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~vsv/papers/arithphys1.pdf) and have a question about the first line of the second paragraph on the first page. It says:

> The basis for this suggestion is the simple fact that all experimental
>   calculations are essentially discrete and so can be modelled by
>   mathematical structures that are over $\mathbb{Q}$.

My question is how we prove that ALL experimental calculations can be modelled without the use of $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: No physical measurement can yield an irrational number: its precision is necessarily finite. (Instead of using the single rational measurement, one can use an interval that takes the precision into account, but then one is working over a different kind of structure altogether.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, What about measuring the area of a circle? It involves $\pi$.

Comment: No, it doesn’t. *Calculating* the area of the circle from the formula $A=\pi r^2$ involves $\pi$; physically *measuring* the area involves using a [planimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter) or other physical mechanism that simply produces a measurement.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, oh I see. It means physical measurement! Thanks a lot!

Comment: That’s right. You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, can I claim that measurements always yield rational numbers because they are events over finite duration of time period?

Comment: I don’t think that the finiteness of the time period is really the issue; rather, it’s simply that measurements always have only finite precision. When you measure a length in cm, for instance, you can get $1.4$, $1.41$, $1.414$, ..., perhaps even $1.41421356237$ or better, but you can’t get $\sqrt2$; you always get a rational number (with an error bar).